# D3 Get Variable Value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

This is a very basic question, but how do I access the value of attributes in d3?
I just started learning today, so I haven't figured this out yet

Suppose I have this as part of my code here
http://jsfiddle.net/matthewpiatetsky/nCNyE/9/

```
   var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
       .data(nodes)
       .enter().append("circle")
       .attr("class", "node")
       .attr("r", function (d) {
        if (width < height){
        return d.count * width/100;
        } else {
        return d.count * height/100;
        }
})
     .on("mouseover", animateFirstStep)
     .on("mouseout",animateSecondStep)
       .style("fill", function(d,i){return color(i);})
       .call(force.drag);
```

For my animation the circle gets bigger when you mouse over it, and I want the circle to return to its normal size when you move the mouse away. However, i'm not sure how to get the value of the radius.

i set the value here

```
.attr("r", function (d) {
        if (width < height){
        return d.count * width/100;
        } else {
        return d.count * height/100;
        }
```

I tried to do node.r and things like that, but i'm not sure what the correct syntax is
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access an attribute of a selection with:

```
var node = svg.selectAll("circle.node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function (d) { return rScale(d.count); })
  .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('r', 1.8 * rScale(d.count));
    })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) { 
    d3.select(this)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('r', rScale(d.count));
  })
  .style("fill", function (d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
 .call(force.drag);
```

in this context, this points to the DOM element binded with d. Normally, the area of a circle must be proportional to the quantities that you are showing, take a look at the documentation of [Quantitative Scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales)s. A fork of your fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yHfRM/1/).

Comment: so how would i do this in a function? function animateZoomIn() {
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()
        .delay(0)
        .duration(2000)
        .attr('r', function(d, i) {
   var radius = d3.select(this).attr('r');
});
};
doesn't work

Comment: should i pass radius as an argument to the function?

Comment: No, this will work when setting an attribute. If you want to use it in a function, you will need to do your selection first and then set the attribute, i.e., function animateZoomIn() { d3.selectAll('circle.node').attr('r', function(d) { // Modify the radius here as shown in the answer });

Comment: I just tried this here, but it didn't seem to have the desired effect unless i'm doing it wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/matthewpiatetsky/xMGwt/1/

Comment: i see, and you added the scale, that's quite helpful! my only question is why is one of the circles not showing up? otherwise that's very niece thank you!

Comment: Good. I am seeing 6 data items and 6 circles. Change the range minimum value to avoid circles of 0 radius.